# RecyclerView display ("Empty") when there is no data at database based on a table

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display ("Empty") at RecyclerView when there are no data available at a table. Now, my currentview when no data is avaialble will like as image below

https://scontent.fkul14-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/60093724_10216107031681720_3339793009188274176_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_eui2=AeE2gJxeFI5ifgJkgcAXJZbsvtp3BiL6w5TtndQ4PO5emnLkh93oOJ_37m6KjbsZJ0QZsU8T6a9q_0Bg38t80eJcwkSiPbye1y9Ad6Ssx2TUrA&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul14-1.fna&oh=2a7d7090bfa7945893bcb973fc26005b&oe=5D5CE2D8

The name "Tan Kian Guan" stay available maybe due to if the user is login, it will get all information about user in table "users".

Below is my code.

MyHistoryList.java

```
    public class MyHistoryList extends AppCompatActivity {

List<User> userList;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
private String approveID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_history_list);

    if(getIntent() != null) {
        approveID = getIntent().getStringExtra("approveType");
    }
    else{}

    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_my_history_list, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvTitle = viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText("MY HISTORY LIST");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    // abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

    userList = new ArrayList<>();

    loadHistory(user.getBadgeid());
}

private void loadHistory(String badgeid) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URLs.URL_LIST+"?badgeid="+ badgeid,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            //getting product object from json array
                            JSONObject userJson = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                userList.add(new User(
                                        userJson.getInt("id"),
                                        userJson.getString("name"),
                                        userJson.getString("badgeid"),
                                        userJson.getString("position"),
                                        userJson.getString("department"),
                                        userJson.getString("factory"),
                                        userJson.getString("reviewer"),
                                        userJson.getString("title"),
                                        userJson.getString("year"),
                                        userJson.getString("month"),
                                        userJson.getString("suggestionwill"),
                                        userJson.getString("present"),
                                        userJson.getString("details"),
                                        userJson.getString("benefit"),
                                        userJson.getString("photo"),
                                        userJson.getString("status"),
                                        userJson.getString("comment")
                                ));
                        }
                        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(MyHistoryList.this, userList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        adapter.setClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                int post = recyclerView.indexOfChild(v);
                                User user = userList.get(post);
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyHistoryList.this, MyHistory.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("user", user);
                                myIntent.putExtra("approveType",approveID);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

activity_my_history_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/haha"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyHistoryList">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Thats the problem in your Response . It should return an Empty list in this case instead of null values ..

Comment: @F. Lampard, Do not add null value in a database

Comment: @RakeshKumar, I dont now why there are valu of null. I never saved it.

Comment: Are you using any local storage? @F.Lampard

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta, I Used MySQL (XAMPP)

Comment: Okay check my answer and let me know. If you were using local storage like SQLite I would have modified my answer. @F.Lampard

Comment: @F.Lampard, You can replace null with empty like this on every those value that you are getting `userJson.getString("name").replace("null","");`

Comment: @RakeshKumar. Work perfect. But the name "Tan Kian Guan" like u see at image Link above still appear. others is okay. I think maybe that name is stored when the user is sign in. any idea?

Comment: @F.Lampard, Are you using that name on the recyclerView to show?? If that then you will have to do the same replace null with blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can know the empty data while you parse the data,

Try this,

**Edit:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/haha"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MyHistoryList">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/emptyView"
                android:text="List is Empty"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_15sp"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Declare textview id in the Activity:

```
 public class MyHistoryList extends AppCompatActivity {

 List<User> userList;
 TextView emptyView;

 RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private String approveID;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_history_list);

 //Declare TextView
 emptyView = findiViewById(R.id.emptyView);

  if(getIntent() != null) {
    approveID = getIntent().getStringExtra("approveType");
  }


private void loadHistory(String badgeid) {
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        URLs.URL_LIST+"?badgeid="+ badgeid,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    //add this condition

                    if(array.length() == 0){
                      //display empty with your code.
                      emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      recylcerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                      emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      recylcerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        //getting product object from json array
                        JSONObject userJson = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            userList.add(new User(
                                    userJson.getInt("id"),
                                    userJson.getString("name"),
                                    userJson.getString("badgeid"),
                                    userJson.getString("position"),
                                    userJson.getString("department"),
                                    userJson.getString("factory"),
                                    userJson.getString("reviewer"),
                                    userJson.getString("title"),
                                    userJson.getString("year"),
                                    userJson.getString("month"),
                                    userJson.getString("suggestionwill"),
                                    userJson.getString("present"),
                                    userJson.getString("details"),
                                    userJson.getString("benefit"),
                                    userJson.getString("photo"),
                                    userJson.getString("status"),
                                    userJson.getString("comment")
                            ));
                    }
                    }
                    UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(MyHistoryList.this, userList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    adapter.setClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int post = recyclerView.indexOfChild(v);
                            User user = userList.get(post);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyHistoryList.this, MyHistory.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("user", user);
                            myIntent.putExtra("approveType",approveID);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

//adding our stringrequest to queue
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

}

This works. Try and let me know. Happy coding.

Comment: Still cannot. Because of the name Tan Kian Guan still appear

Comment: I got it. You need to hide the recyclerview layout . I am editing my answer please check it @F.Lampard

Comment: still cannot. because name "Tan Kian Guan" you can see at image link is still appear

Comment: I'll fix it @F.Lampard

Comment: basically, when user login, all user details will bring together (name, staff id, staff email, etc). When the user submits the suggestion, save to the database and display at History. But if the worker never sends any suggestion. the list should empty. I think maybe due to I bring all user information after login

Comment: So you are saving the database in the app? @F.Lampard

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The suggestions are going to be displayed in the recyclerview? @F.Lampard

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem by making recyclerview visibility as gone. If we hide recyclerview when there is no data. Why is the name "Tan Kian Guan" still appears? @F.Lampard

Comment: I think maybe due to I bring all user information after login @g.brahma Datta

Comment: It doesn't matter if you bring the data from the server when the server has no data my code should work. You're doing mistake somewhere I guess @F.Lampard

Comment: Have you got the answer ? @F.Lampard

Comment: Your answer was absolutely correct. I change some mistake at my User class.

Comment: Thank you. You can also upvote the answer so it reaches more people. I'm glad it help you @F.Lampard

Comment: @ g.brahma Datta, Im glad if you can solve my problem at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145203/keep-checked-radiobutton-although-the-apps-is-killed-sharedpreferences

Comment: Yeah sure @F.Lampard

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available" />
```

**in your class file**

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
if(response==null){
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.Gone) 
emptyView.setVisibility(View.Visible)
}else{
    try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);      
    //add this condition
    if(array.length() == 0){
```

Comment: At which line need to put if statement?

Comment: in your onResponse method, before you create JSONArray object.